# Цветовая схема activity в android studio по умолчанию

Tags: android, android-studio

При открытии какого-либо [activity].xml в android studio 2022.3.1(Giraffe) `System UI Mode` всегда становится "Not Night":

[image: Not Night]

Происходит это независимо от того какой последний перед выходом режим был установлен.
Можно ли каким-либо способом поставить тему по умолчанию?